# Xamarain support for IOS 17.4.1

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

We have a mobile application build in Xamarin, as Microsoft has closed support for it, so is there any other way we can support different IOS version until end of this year.

Answer (score 0):

Please be noted that Xamarin support will end on May 1, 2024 for all Xamarin SDKs including Xamarin.Forms. Android API 34 and `Xcode 15 SDKs` (`iOS and iPadOS 17`, `macOS 14`) will be the final versions Xamarin will target from existing Xamarin SDKs (i.e. no new APIs are planned). That implies, you can still build or publish your Xamarin iOS apps but you can't use new APIs which are included in the new released iOS versions.

For supporting `iOS 17.4`, there's a known issue:[[META] Xcode 15.3 Support for .NET 8 and MAUI #20257](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/20257), you can refer to it.

Reference link:[Xamarin & Xamarin.Forms End of Support](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/platform/support/policy/xamarin#:%7E:text=Xamarin%20support%20will%20end%20on%20May%201%2C%202024,Xamarin%20SDKs%20%28i.e.%20no%20new%20APIs%20are%20planned%29).